# UWP XAML Button Content Template

Tags: c#, xaml, button, uwp, contenttemplate

I am trying to find a cleaner solution to displaying the content of a button control the way that I want it.

Basically, I my goal is to make a button that functions as a Grid, but retains all the functionality of a Button. So it is clickable, but doesn't squish the content. (Sort of like Windows Tiles)

To accomplish this currently, I can place a grid within a button control, but then I have to manually set the height and width. I want this to by dynamic and stretch to the width and height of the button.

This is the current template that I am trying to edit. I am open to creating a custom style for the ContentTemplate, but I have not had much luck. Any help is appreciated! Also open to any clean solution.

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonTest" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundAccentBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForeground}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>

    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"/>
    <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualMargin" Value="-3"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBackgroundPointerOver}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderBrushPointerOver}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForegroundPointerOver}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBackgroundPressed}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderBrushPressed}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForegroundPressed}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBackgroundDisabled}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderBrushDisabled}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForegroundDisabled}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <!--Somehow need to stick Content={TemplateResource Content}-->
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

For reference, this is how I have been doing the buttons in the past. It gets the job done but it is not dynamic to the changing in screen size.

```
<Button x:Name="TileButton" Margin="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Grid.Row="3" Style="{StaticResource ButtonTileStyle}">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="-8,-4" Width="113" Height="123">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Image Grid.Row="1" Source="..."/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="Label" Text="Label" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="5,0,0,2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" TextAlignment="Left"/>
        </Grid>
    </Button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just want this?

PoC:

```
<Style x:Key="CWButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBackground}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForeground}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderThemeThickness}"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8,4,8,4"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"/>
    <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualMargin" Value="-3"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBackgroundPointerOver}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderBrushPointerOver}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForegroundPointerOver}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBackgroundPressed}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderBrushPressed}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForegroundPressed}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBackgroundDisabled}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderBrushDisabled}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForegroundDisabled}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                    <Rectangle Fill="Red"/>
                    <Rectangle Fill="Green" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Grid.Row="1"/>
                    <Rectangle Fill="Gray" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="1"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="2" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="3" Grid.Row="1"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="4" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>

                    <!-- Put this guy in a grid cell or could make it appear over center if you like. -->
                    <ContentPresenter Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                      x:Name="ContentPresenter" 
                                      AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" 
                                      BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                                      BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                                      ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" 
                                      ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" 
                                      Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" 
                                      HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                                      Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                                      VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

and at the instance...

```
<Button Content="Blah"
        Height="150" Width="150"
        Foreground="White"
        FontSize="35"
        Style="{StaticResource CWButtonStyle}"/>
```

Hope this helps, cheers :)